# Can't save a file in a project that has a react app and a basic python backend file

Tags: python, reactjs

I created a folder on my desktop that contains a React app (created using `sudo npx create-react-app`) and another folder called backend which contains a python file. The folder opens up in VSCode just fine and I can make edits to the file, but when I try to save I get the following error:

> Failed to save 'App.js': Command failed: "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" --file-write "/Users/poojittummalapalli/Library/Application Support/Code/code-elevated-6FnboXfs" "/Users/poojittummalapalli/Desktop/chatClient/client/src/App.js" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/Users/poojittummalapalli/Desktop/chatClient/client/src/App.js'

I tried various solutions on youtube and stack overflow but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: check folder permissions, usually a public allowed folder works on your scenario